# Where can I find the application.exe.config file in my C# project?

Tags: c#, configuration

Where can I find the application.exe.config file in my C# project?

I'm attempting to enable the JIT debugger but cannot find the config file.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually in the root of your project. If its not there you might not have one. You can add it by right clicking on your project and add new item.

It's called App.Config at this point. Once you compile it is then renamed to AppName.exe.Config, and placed with your build output.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the post-compilation application configuration file.

Comment: Could be, since he mentioned c# project I thought otherwise, btw both of us we have the complete answer

Answer (score 2):

I had to learn that each project in the solution can have a settings file. But the one in the startup project is the one that becomes application.exe.config in your output folder.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in `\bin\Debug` or `\bin\Release`, right next to your compiled assembly.

Answer (score 1):

It will be app.config . App.exe.config will be created in case of windows app,test project or asp project or any other projec which shows output