# Location of applicationname.exe.config in C#

Tags: c#, configuration

Where I can find the applicationname.exe.config file in my Windows form application. 
[Where can I find the application exe...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678828/where-can-i-find-the-application-exe-config-file-in-my-c-project) mentioned that config file should be placed in Release or Debug files. But I cannot see the file in those places.

Also, I manually copied the config file from project root directory and past it in Release directory. Still the changes are not effected.

Then, I renamed the config as applicationname.exe.config, still the not effected.

Anybody can tell me how can I overcome ?

Comment: You are mentioning changes. What exactly is the problem you are trying to overcome?

Comment: Basically I want to make a release version and some parameters are feasible to change. for an instance DB url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the same folder as applicationname.exe. That is generally where the config files are for win forms applications.

If it is not there, you can create a new one, with the name applicationname.exe.config.

Comment: That is what I mentioned, I did but was not effected.

Comment: Ok, did you create a new config file?

Comment: not exactly, I manually copied the config from root. Then I alternate it and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this path. i.e, inside bin folder

```
C:\Documents and Settings\deepika\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug
```

Comment: That assumes where the project files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
string path = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] + ".config";
```